# White slide transition with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, transition, slide

I'm just wondering how to make an animation to slide to another page when I click my buttons on the right of my website.I want the header and footer that is in black to stay in tact but when a button is clicked on the right I want the white space to slide to the next page.

Also how do I get text to appear when I hover over the buttons, I can't seem to make it happen?

Here is my code for anybody who wishes to help

> CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: volkorn;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Top Black Section */
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
/* Top Black Section */

/* White Area */
.white-content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
/* White Area */

/* Bottom Black Section */
.bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
/* Bottom Black Section */

.ulogo {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40%; 
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 250px; 
    text-align: center;

}
/* Bottom Black Section */

/* Right Navigation */
.right-nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: calc(50% - 120px);
}
.right-nav div {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #C0C0C0 ;
    transition: color .3s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.right-nav div:hover {
    color: #404040;
}




/* Right Navigation */
```

> HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<title>Upload Festival</title>  
    <head> 
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/customization.css" rel="stylesheet" style="text/css">
    <!-- CSS -->

    <!-- jQuery&WebFont -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.10/webfont.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery&WebFont -->
  </head>

<body class="index">
    <!-- Top Border -->
<div class="top-bar"></div>
<!-- Top Border --> 

<!-- White Content -->
<div class="white-content"></div>
<!-- White Content -->

<!-- Bottom Bar -->
<div class="bottom-bar"></div>
<!-- Bottom Bar -->


<!--Buttons-->
<div class="right-nav">
<div id="b1">&bull;</div>
<div id="b2">&bull;</div>
<div id="b3">&bull;</div>
<div id="b4">&bull;</div>
</div>
<!--Buttons-->

<!--Logo div-->
<div class="logo"></div>
<!--Logo div-->

<!--Transition Section-->
<div class="slider"></div>
<!--Transition Section-->

<!-- Logo - Left -->
<img class ="ulogo" src="images/upload-logo.png">
<!-- Logo - Left -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put all this in js fiddle. this can be done with anchor link trigger.. i can show you how if you can put code on fiddle

Comment: Sure thing - http://jsfiddle.net/kLunbwqo/

Comment: Just put the relevant code in fiddle please. and where is your navigation section? what is your target ? is it another html DOM element or a totally different page? I see you have put a hover pseudo class to the "div" but then what? In short, what exactly have you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kLunbwqo/1/ - My target is to keep the same page, I don't want a totally different page I just want the white section which will have content on it like text, images etc to transition to another section which has content on it when I click a button but only for it to change in the white space no-where else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using radio buttons and sibling CSS selectors. The basic idea is to put the buttons and the slides in the same container so that they are siblings.

The radio buttons might each look something like:

```
<label class="radiolabel b1" for="b1">&bull;</label>
<input type="radio" id="b1" name="nav-buttons" class="button-radio" />
```

The button labels can still be positioned where you have the navigation area now.

You then put your content in a slide container like:

```
<div class="slide slide1">...content... </div>
```

where the second class number increments.

Then position them off-screen with:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    -ms-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
}
```

Now you can tie them to the buttons like:

```
#b1:checked ~ .slide1 {
    left: 0;
}
```

So, in this case, when the first radio button is selected, the first slide is moved onto the screen.

There are bits and pieces of other HTML and CSS you will need to adjust according to your needs.

I did a quick-and-dirty example in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/d3pdkxnd/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this if exactly what you want because my english is not good... sorry. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ga557px/)

I add to your fiddle some JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$('.right-nav div').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.slide').removeClass('active');
    if ( id == 'b1' ) {
        $('.sl1').addClass('active');
    }
    else if ( id == 'b2' ) {
        $('.sl2').addClass('active');
    }
    else if ( id == 'b3' ) {
        $('.sl3').addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

And some CSS to yours:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
}
.slider .slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.slider .slide.sl1 {
        margin-left:100%;    
}
.slider .slide.sl2 {
        margin-left: 200%;    
}
.slider .slide.sl3 {
        margin-left: 300%;
}
.slider .slide.active {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I want but I mean I want the whole white space to move into new content that I want to place

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you want (my english is so bad :((( )